# Android: I cannot download with my own app browser

Tags: android, browser, download-manager

As shown in the attached image below, my Android application refuses to react to click on the "Browse" button.

I mean :

1. When the App is not installed, it downloads files without any problem.
2. But, when the App is installed (it takes control browsers), the "Browse" button does not work.

Do you think it's related to permissions in my App manifest or it is something else?

My minSdkVersion is 11 and my target is Android 4.0.3 Build.